# Physical PCI order reference to CPU

Tags: ubuntu

Is there any ways to know the order of PCI in reference to the CPU (or in reference to something?)?

for example, I have 5 AMD cards, I would like to know which one is which in reference to something (physically). I can use `lshw` to find out the order (through PCI-X, where X is the integer), like the 3rd card is not working, but I need a reference so that I can quickly identify the card physically on the board. I suppose each motherboard manufacture is different, even the order won't change (PCI won't be jumping around like 1,3,2,5,4), so it's either clock-wise or counter-clock-wise?

here's a piece of my `lshw` info

```
yoshie
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
      description: System memory
      physical id: 0
      size: 3407MiB
     *-cpu
      product: AMD Embedded G-Series GX-224IJ Radeon R4E
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
      physical id: 1
      bus info: cpu@0
      size: 2400MHz
      capacity: 2400MHz
      width: 64 bits
      capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc rep_good acc_power nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext ptsc mwaitx cpb hw_pstate vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 xsaveopt arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic overflow_recov cpufreq
     *-pci:0
      description: Host bridge
      product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
    *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
         version: 81
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
         resources: iomemory:f0-ef irq:232 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:ff0800000-ff0ffffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:feb00000-feb3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
    *-multimedia
         description: Audio device
         product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 1.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
         version: 00
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
         resources: iomemory:f0-ef irq:239 memory:ffff00000-ffff03fff
    *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 2.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:216 ioport:9000(size=20480) memory:fe500000-fe9fffff ioport:f60000000(size=2418016256)
       *-pci
            description: PCI bridge
            product: ASMedia Technology Inc.
            vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            version: 00
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=pcieport
            resources: irq:218 ioport:9000(size=20480) memory:fe500000-fe9fffff ioport:f60000000(size=2418016256)
          *-pci:0
               description: PCI bridge
               product: ASMedia Technology Inc.
               vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
               physical id: 1
               bus info: pci@0000:02:01.0
               version: 00
               width: 32 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
               configuration: driver=pcieport
               resources: irq:220
          *-pci:1
               description: PCI bridge
               product: ASMedia Technology Inc.
               vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
               physical id: 2
               bus info: pci@0000:02:02.0
               version: 00
               width: 32 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
               configuration: driver=pcieport
               resources: irq:222
          *-pci:2
               description: PCI bridge
               product: ASMedia Technology Inc.
               vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
               physical id: 3
               bus info: pci@0000:02:03.0
               version: 00
               width: 32 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
               configuration: driver=pcieport
               resources: irq:224 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:fe900000-fe9fffff ioport:fe0000000(size=270532608)
             *-display
                  description: VGA compatible controller
                  product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  physical id: 0
                  bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
                  version: cf
                  width: 64 bits
                  clock: 33MHz
                  capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                  configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
                  resources: iomemory:f0-ef iomemory:f0-ef irq:233 memory:fe0000000-fefffffff memory:ff0000000-ff01fffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe900000-fe93ffff memory:fe940000-fe95ffff
             *-multimedia
                  description: Audio device
                  product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  physical id: 0.1
                  bus info: pci@0000:05:00.1
                  version: 00
                  width: 64 bits
                  clock: 33MHz
                  capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                  configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                  resources: irq:240 memory:fe960000-fe963fff
          *-pci:3
               description: PCI bridge
               product: ASMedia Technology Inc.
               vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
               physical id: 4
               bus info: pci@0000:02:04.0
               version: 00
               width: 32 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
               configuration: driver=pcieport
               resources: irq:225 ioport:c000(size=4096) memory:fe800000-fe8fffff ioport:fc0000000(size=270532608)
             *-display
                  description: VGA compatible controller
                  product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  physical id: 0
                  bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
                  version: cf
                  width: 64 bits
                  clock: 33MHz
                  capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                  configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
                  resources: iomemory:f0-ef iomemory:f0-ef irq:234 memory:fc0000000-fcfffffff memory:fd0000000-fd01fffff ioport:c000(size=256) memory:fe800000-fe83ffff memory:fe840000-fe85ffff
             *-multimedia
                  description: Audio device
                  product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  physical id: 0.1
                  bus info: pci@0000:06:00.1
                  version: 00
                  width: 64 bits
                  clock: 33MHz
                  capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                  configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                  resources: irq:241 memory:fe860000-fe863fff
          *-pci:4
               description: PCI bridge
               product: ASMedia Technology Inc.
               vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
               physical id: 5
               bus info: pci@0000:02:05.0
               version: 00
               width: 32 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
               configuration: driver=pcieport
               resources: irq:226 ioport:b000(size=4096) memory:fe700000-fe7fffff ioport:fa0000000(size=270532608)
             *-display
                  description: VGA compatible controller
                  product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  physical id: 0
                  bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
                  version: cf
                  width: 64 bits
                  clock: 33MHz
                  capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                  configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
                  resources: iomemory:f0-ef iomemory:f0-ef irq:235 memory:fa0000000-fafffffff memory:fb0000000-fb01fffff ioport:b000(size=256) memory:fe700000-fe73ffff memory:fe740000-fe75ffff
             *-multimedia
                  description: Audio device
                  product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  physical id: 0.1
                  bus info: pci@0000:07:00.1
                  version: 00
                  width: 64 bits
                  clock: 33MHz
                  capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                  configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                  resources: irq:242 memory:fe760000-fe763fff
          *-pci:5
               description: PCI bridge
               product: ASMedia Technology Inc.
               vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
               physical id: 6
               bus info: pci@0000:02:06.0
               version: 00
               width: 32 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
               configuration: driver=pcieport
               resources: irq:227 ioport:a000(size=4096) memory:fe600000-fe6fffff ioport:f80000000(size=270532608)
             *-display
                  description: VGA compatible controller
                  product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  physical id: 0
                  bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
                  version: cf
                  width: 64 bits
                  clock: 33MHz
                  capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                  configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
                  resources: iomemory:f0-ef iomemory:f0-ef irq:236 memory:f80000000-f8fffffff memory:f90000000-f901fffff ioport:a000(size=256) memory:fe600000-fe63ffff memory:fe640000-fe65ffff
             *-multimedia
                  description: Audio device
                  product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  physical id: 0.1
                  bus info: pci@0000:08:00.1
                  version: 00
                  width: 64 bits
                  clock: 33MHz
                  capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                  configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                  resources: irq:243 memory:fe660000-fe663fff
          *-pci:6
               description: PCI bridge
               product: ASMedia Technology Inc.
               vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
               physical id: 7
               bus info: pci@0000:02:07.0
               version: 00
               width: 32 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
               configuration: driver=pcieport
               resources: irq:228 ioport:9000(size=4096) memory:fe500000-fe5fffff ioport:f60000000(size=270532608)
             *-display
                  description: VGA compatible controller
                  product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  physical id: 0
                  bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
                  version: cf
                  width: 64 bits
                  clock: 33MHz
                  capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                  configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
                  resources: iomemory:f0-ef iomemory:f0-ef irq:237 memory:f60000000-f6fffffff memory:f70000000-f701fffff ioport:9000(size=256) memory:fe500000-fe53ffff memory:fe540000-fe55ffff
             *-multimedia
                  description: Audio device
                  product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                  physical id: 0.1
                  bus info: pci@0000:09:00.1
                  version: 00
                  width: 64 bits
                  clock: 33MHz
                  capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                  configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                  resources: irq:244 memory:fe560000-fe563fff
    *-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 2.4
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.4
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:216 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:fea00000-feafffff ioport:f0000000(size=1048576)
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
            logical name: enp10s0
            version: 0c
            serial: dc:9c:52:07:6b:4c
            size: 1Gbit/s
            capacity: 1Gbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=172.16.2.45 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
            resources: irq:230 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea00fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
...
```

Comment: `lshw` outputs a lot of unnecessary noise.  `lspci | grep VGA` is adequate to get a list of GPUs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Motherboard manufacturers **usually**(*) do the physical layout of PCI-e slots so that they are in consecutive logical device order.  And the order is **usually** from closest-to-the-CPU to farthest-from-the-CPU.

Your GPUs are on:

```
00:00:01.0
00:05:00.0
00:06:00.0
00:07:00.0
00:08:00.0
00:09:00.0
```

We can ignore the first one, because that's probably a GPU built-in to the CPU.  The rest are listed in the order that they are physically installed into slots - e.g. 00:05:00.0 will be the GPU in the first slot, 00:06:00.0 will be the CPU in the 2nd slot.

---

(*) I hesitate to say "always" but I've never seen a motherboard with a different layout.  Almost certainly because it would be more work (and thus more expensive) to do that.  Note that if a manufacturer ever discovers a way that they can save a few nano-cents per motherboard by doing it differently, that's exactly what they will do.

Motherboards with PCI risers and additional PCI bridges etc will change this, but you don't tend to see them outside of server boards for 1 or 2RU rackmount chassis...and even then, the order is still (usually) from closest to farthest.

Comment: I did confirm that the order are correct in my dev machine, but the deployed machine that I worked on is backward. I would like to 100% confirm the order (reference to CPU), is there any other way?

Comment: "closest-to-cpu" is electrically closest, which is not necessarily the same as physically closest (usually is, but a consumer never really knows how the sausage was made).   i would suggest that you label the cards when you install them.  label them with at least brand, model, and `lspci` slot id.